# phyloseq plot_ordination con flechas

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trabajo en microbiota e intento generar un gráfico PCoA desde un objeto phyloseq en el que aparezcan flechas indicando los taxones que más importancia tiene en la separación de los puntos. Es algo smilar a lo que se ve en esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35924085/change-loadings-arrows-length-in-pca-plot-using-ggplot2-ggfortify) pero partiendo de un objeto phyloseq. Este es el código que he utilizado pero no he podido encontrar en ninguna parte como seguir adelante para conseguir lo que quiero, ni en inglés ni en español.

```r
distbray <- distance(ps_aa, method="bray")
pcordinationbray = ordinate(ps_aa, method="PCoA", distbray)
plot_ordination(ps_aa, pcordinationbray, type="samples", color = sample_variables(ps_aa) + 
   theme_classic() +
   theme(strip.background = element_blank()) +
   ggtitle ("PCoA Bray Curtis Distance") +
   geom_point(size=3)
```

[image: Result from my code]

Hay otra cosa que me gustaría hacer. Es para agregar una flecha que une el centro de las elipses que puedo dibujar con la siguiente línea de código adicional.

```r
stat_ellipse(type="norm",linetype=2)  # Add elipses
```

[image: PCoA with ellipses]

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, estás en StackOverflow en ESPAÑOL, por favor [edit] tu pregunta en el idioma de la comunidad para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario. Escribí en inglés porque estoy acostumbrado a buscar estas cosas en inglés pero me es más cómodo en español